# Difference in .tar.gz and first gz and then tar

Tags: linux, tar, gunzip

I made two compressed copy of my folder, first by using the command `tar czf dir.tar.gz dir`
This gives me an archive of size ~16kb. Then I tried another method, first i gunzipped all files inside the dir and then used

```
gzip ./dir/*
tar cf dir.tar dir/*.gz
```

but the second method gave me dir.tar of size ~30kb (almost double). Why there is so much difference in size?

Comment: I would create two temporary directories and unzip/untar each of the items you think you have zipped. Before proceeding further, I'd appreciate if you can confirm you really did zip up everything you intended to zip up and no more/no less. Thanks.

Comment: I used gzip to zip every file inside dir

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because zip process in general is more efficient on big sample than on small files. You have zipped 100 files of 1ko for example. Each file will have a certain compression, plus the [overhead of the gzip format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip#File_format).

```
file1.tar -> files1.tar.gz  (admit 30 bytes of headers/footers)
file2.tar -> files2.tar.gz  (admit 30 bytes of headers/footers)
...
file100.tar -> files100.tar.gz  (admit 30 bytes of headers/footers)
------------------------------
30*100 = 3ko of overhead.
```

But if you try to compress a `tar` file of 100ko (which contains your 100 files), the overhead of the gzip format will be added only one time (instead of 100 times) and the compression can be better)

Answer (score 3):

Overhead from the per-file metadata and suboptimal conpression by `gzip` when processing files individually resulting from `gzip` not observing data in full and thus compressing with suboptimal dictionary (which is reset after each file).

Answer (score -3):

`tar cf` should create an uncompressed archive, it means the size of your directory should almost be the same as your archive, maybe even more.

`tar czf` will run `gunzip` compression through it.

This can be further checked by doing a `man tar` in shell prompt in Linux,

```
   -z, --gzip, --gunzip, --ungzip
          filter the archive through gzip
```